# Use of a diagram in a publication

Tags: discussion

I am a PhD student and I'm conducting research into the measurement of citrate in human biofluids using the indirect citric lyase method. The final step involves the differential absorbance of NADH/NAD+ at 340nm. I've found a very useful diagram on your website and would respectfully request permission to use it. The URL is listed below.

[Why does NADH have 2 peaks in its absorption spectrum but NAD+ has only one?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63186/why-does-nadh-have-2-peaks-in-its-absorption-spectrum-but-nad-has-only-one)

Kind regards,
Chris

Comment: See [this](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/i-need-permission-to-reuse-photo-from-user-porphyrin-answer-on-question-about) meta post for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see what the problem is.
[The image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NADNADH.svg) has been taken from Wikipedia article [Nicotinamide adenine dinucleotide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_adenine_dinucleotide).
There is note from the creator that the image belongs to the public domain:

> I, the copyright holder of this work, release this work into the [public domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain). This applies worldwide.
>   In some countries this may not be legally possible; if so:
>   *I grant anyone the right to use this work for any purpose, without any conditions, unless such conditions are required by law.*

This means you can reuse the image as is, or trace the image and re-plot the data to keep your original manuscript style.

Comment: Thanks for tracking it down. I tried to reverse google image search, not sure why I didn't find it...

Comment: @orthocresol I just clicked the first link in the question and scrolled down two times. That was my tracking method:D